# jQuery Flexslider has stopped working

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I have been using Flexslider successfully on a mobile site but it has recently stopped working and I can't understand why.  The images are loading but displaying a huge white space that is far bigger than the dimensions I set.

http://www.johnwhiteman.co.uk/mobile/LettingsDetails.aspx?ID=P1135

Can anyone shed any light on this?

The page runs off the following master page:

```
    <html lang="en-gb" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb">
    <head runat="server">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link href="mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../highslide/highslide.css" />
      <link href="flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../Javascript/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Javascript/jquery.flexslider.js">    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        InitializeImageSlider();
    });
    function InitializeImageSlider() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: true,
            directionNav: true,
            itemWidth: "100%",
            itemHeight: "200px"
        });
    }
</script>

     <script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-10268625-14']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>

</head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../highslide/highslide.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

    hs.graphicsDir = '../highslide/graphics/';

   </script>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <a href="Default.aspx" class="leftbutton">Home</a> <a href="Contact.aspx" class="rightbutton">
                Contact Us</a>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


        </div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the page itself is

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="MasterMobile.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="LettingsDetails.aspx.vb" Inherits="LettingsDetailsMobile" %>
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/LettingsSearch.aspx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <div id="details">
        <asp:Repeater ID="myDataRepeater" runat="server" Visible="true">
            <itemtemplate>


                <div id="divImageSlider" class="flexslider" runat="server">
                </div>
                  <h1>
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PropertyName")%>

                </h1>
                <p style="font-weight: 800"> &pound<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Price")%>
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PricePrefix")%> Reference:  <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PropertyID")%></p>
                <p class="justify">
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ShortDescription")%></p>

                <!--<asp:Button ID="btnMapGoogle" runat="server" Text="View on Map" Width="40%" PostBackUrl='<%#"http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PostCode")%>' />-->

<table class="options">
<tr><td style="text-align:center"> <a class="linkbutton" href='<%#"http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PostCode")%>'> View on Map</a></td><td style="text-align:center"> <a class="linkbutton" href='<%#"mailto:?subject=Check out this property at John Whiteman - " & DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PropertyName") & "&body=Have a look at this rental property: http://www.johnwhiteman.co.uk/LettingsDetails.aspx?ID=" & DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PropertyID")%>' >Share this Property</a></td></tr>
<tr><td style="text-align:center"><asp:Button ID="btnViewing" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%#"RequestViewing.aspx?ID="+ DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.PropertyID")%>' Text="Request Viewing" /></td><td style="text-align:center"><asp:Button ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="Back"   PostBackUrl="LettingsSearch.aspx" /></td></tr>
</table>







            </itemtemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks

Helen

Comment: I took a quick look at this with a web inspector and couldn't find the problem. Can you post your code please?

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I've added the code for you.

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation for flexslider, and I'm not seing "itemheight".  Can you try just loading flexslider with no additional parameters to see what happens? I was able to remove the inline styles applied to the li elements and it got rid of the extra whitespace.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I have removed itemheight and ItemWidth but to no effect. The flex viewport has a huge max sixe of 2000px but I cannot find where this is set.